# List not iterable

Tags: mybatis

I have a problem with MyBatis,
I can't give names for variables and so on...
Confidential data, I prefer not to give :)
I have this error :

```
org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression '<liste_name>'.  Return value ( <all values in list separated with comma here> ) was not iterable.
```

Java :

```
List<BigDecimal> <liste_name> = Stream.of(<one String variable>.split(",")).map(BigDecimal.new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    BigDecimal <one_id> = [recuperation here of the id...]
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("<liste_name>", <liste_name>);
    map.put("<one_id>",<one id>);
    return <call here SQL request>(map);
```

SQL

```
[begining of SQL request...]
WHERE <col number 1> = <one_id>
AND <col number 2> IN
<foreach open="(" separator="," close=")" collection="<liste_name>" item="<item_name>">
    #{<item_name>}
</foreach>
[end of SQL request...]
```

Thank you very, very, very much to help me :)

Comment: It's a very basic usage and should just work, so you may be doing something unusual. With the information you provided, however, it is impossible for others to solve your problem. Please create a small demo app like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues). You can use dummy table/column/variable names, but make sure we can reproduce the same error.

Comment: It seems your parameter `<liste_name>` is a comma-separated String rather than a java.util.List. For testing purposes you should create the java.util.List in a simpler way, just by adding numbers, and see if it works. Then you can add the parsing.

Comment: Also `Stream.of()` does not work well with primitives types such as `int`. Better use `Arrays.stream()`.